# Problem with a instance and a Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, instance

I try to work on a Force based 2D ship game.
I have Forces, that a stored in a Dictionary, for 'Jets' on a ship. So I just have to say the name, the amplitude and let the engine do the acceleration/rotation.

For that I have to rotate the force into the local coordinates of the ship, before I can apply it, but instead only rotating the new force, it also rotates the force stored in the Dictionary. What causes the Force to spin around.

```
Force f1 = new Force();
f1 = Player.JetsDict["RearRight"];
f1.Position = Vector2.Transform(f1.Position, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Player.Rotation));
```

while this code dose not change the instance stored in the dictionary (but I don't want to use it, as its longer, and I got many forces to handle):

```
Force f1 = new Force();
f1.Position = Player.JetsDict["RearRight"].Position;
f1.Vector = Player.JetsDict["RearRight"].Vector;
f1.Position = Vector2.Transform(f1.Position, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Player.Rotation));
```

Why?

Greg the Mad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Force` is defined as a class (`class Force`), when you get the copy out of the Dictionary, you're just getting a reference to a Force instance - the same Force instance that's stored in the Dictionary.  Making a change to members within that reference will be reflected everywhere in your program that uses it.

The only option here is to make a new instance.  This is what you're doing in the second case.

However, if the Force is nothing but a Position and a Vector, I would consider making this a struct instead of a class.  Structs are always copied by value instead of by reference, which would cause your original code to work the way you expect.  If there is more to it, however, a class may still be the best option, in which case the second option is the best potential solution.

You could shorten it, though, by adding a new constructor that took a Force as an argument, and copied the Position + Vecotr.  That would let you write:

```
Force f1 = new Force(Player.JetsDict["RearRight"]);
f1.Position = Vector2.Transform(f1.Position, Matrix.CreateRotationZ(Player.Rotation));
```

Comment: OK, thanks that helps a lot. Thanks you, and the others that have commented.

Answer (score 0):

```
Force f1 = new Force();
f1 = Player.JetsDict["RearRight"];
```

That code resets `f1`'s reference to that of the one in your dictionary.  `f1` is then an alias to the element of the dictionary.  When you change it, you change what's in the dictionary.

What you want is a .clone() function on `Force`:

```
Force f1 = Player.JetsDict["RearRight"].clone();
```

or a copy constructor:

```
Force f1 = new Force(Player.JetsDict["RearRight"]);
```

Comment: BTW - If you're going to use Cloning (which has other issues), you might want to implement IClonable and make it "Clone()" [instead of clone()].

Answer (score 0):

What gets stored in the dictionary is a *reference* to the instance of `Force` (assuming it's a class, not a struct). If you modify the object which the value refers to, then it stays modified.

My guess is that you don't currently have a firm grasp of reference types and value types... I have an [article](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) which may help you. This is a really key topic to understand.

It's a bit like two people having the same friend's address in their phonebook: if I look up my friend's address and then paint the front door of their house red, and then *you* look up the same person's address and visit their house, you'll see a red front door. The important thing is that the *house* isn't in the phone book - only the address is. Likewise the `Force` *object* isn't in the dictionary - only a reference is.